# pubnub subscribe timeout randomly

Tags: android, pubnub

My pubnub subscribe object creates and operates successfully, after some time it times out randomly, first error message says "Unable to obtain Response Code", seconds later it says "Timeout occured". Out of, for example, 3 devices subscribed, only one will timeout while the other 2 stay connected. Im using android by the way.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a comment why. Vernon, we'll get you an answer soon.